# iOS game performance increases during profiling

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit

I have been developing a SpriteKit game in Xcode targeting the iPhone4 as my weakest device. The FPS has been terrible, and I am working to improve it. When I ran instruments to time profile my game, the FPS was a perfect 60. So this has me thinking that I have been building my game with some configuration that hurts the performance, perhaps a debug mode of some kind. I have not changed very many of the project settings from the default SpriteKit project.

I do not know enough about iOS to figure out what changed to increase the performance of my game. Which setting is causing the slowdown?

Comment: Your assumption is true. Profile runs on 'release' mode (which is optimized). On the other hand 'debug' is not optimized for performance (but is configured for, well, debugging). Having said that... if your project is in Swift then the performance issues are probably because of it (1.2 though seems to be much faster). The relevant setting (just to find the culprit) would be Swift Compiler - Code Generation > Optimization Level (it is 'None' on debug and 'Fastest' on Release). I hope that this makes sense.

Comment: That was it. This is such a great incidental finding for me. I spent the last few weeks thinking I was just a terrible programmer. Now my game actually runs smoothly and I can get back to features.